# Usando a função getColletion no PyMongo

Tags: python, pymongo

alguma consegue me ajudar com o seguinte problema?

Dentro do mongoDB, a colletion foi criada com espaço, exemplo: "mkt pipe". O mongoDB permiti fazer esse tipo de coisa.

Criei a seguinte rota para realizar a consulta diretamente no banco de dados:

```
@metricas.route('/counter_source', methods=['POST'])

    def counter_source():
        payload = json.loads(request.data, object_hook=datetime_parser)
        query = payload.get("query")
        count = app.db.getCollection("mkt pipe").find(query).count()
    
        return str(count)
```

por conta do getCollection o pymongo me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'getCollection' method on a 'Database' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

Se não fosse o bendito espaço, bastava fazer assim que funcionava:

```
count = app.db.mktpipe.find(query).count()
```

Alguém já teve esse problema que possa me ajudar?

Abraço

Comment: Tem certeza que o método `getCollection` existe? Já tentou `app.db["mkt pipe"].find(query).count()`?

Comment: @PauloMarques assim funciona sim. Único método que não tinha lembrado de testar. Obrigado